# Product of derivatives of a convex function

Tags: differential-equations, convexity

Given a well-behaved function $f(x,t)$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}<0$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}>0$, is there a way to show
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}\right)^2 > \left(\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x^3}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)
\end{equation}
or under what conditions this applies? I've tried to brute-force it with forward finite differences and it's equivalent to
\begin{equation}
(f(x+2h)-f(x+h))^2 > (f(x+3h)-f(x+2h))(f(x+h)-f(x))
\end{equation}
but that's where I get stuck. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can hide the parameter $t$ that plays no role. You may also replace $f$ with $f(-x)$ so now $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)>0$. Then, the inequality now is  $f'''f' > (f'')^2$, which exactly says that $f'$ is a logarithmically convex function.

Comment: (so, for the old $f$, it is $-f'$ log.c.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can find a way to prove log convexity for $-f'$.

Comment: What is $t$ doing in your question?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, $t$ is there because the full problem is a PDE with a known terminal boundary condition $g(x,T)$. I think I can assume the above inequality holds for that boundary condition. Further, $g(0,t) = k>0$ and $g(\infty,t) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about $f$; consider $g(x):=\ln(-f'_x)$: it is well defined. Then you say that $g'<0$ and ask if this implies that $g''>0$. Why would this be true?

Comment: I might be misinterpreting your notation: $g(x) = \ln\left(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)$ implies that $g'(x) = \frac{f_{xx}}{f_x}$ (where subscripts denote partial derivatives), so how does the original equation imply $g'<0$?

Comment: You claim that $f_x<0$ and $f_{xx}>0$, don't you?

Comment: Right, sorry, I misread it.